# Por defecto opción marcada en un select dinamico

Tags: php, select

tengo un select que lleno con la base de datos de países, pero me gustaria que saliese por defecto un país marcado, ya que este país sera la selección habitual.

```
<select class="form-control formContact" name="pais" id="pais" required>
   <option value="">Selecciona un país</option>
      @foreach ($paises as $pais)
        <option value="{{ $pais->codigo }}"> {{ $pais->pais }}</option> 
      @endforeach
</select>
```

El value por defecto tendría que ser `ES`. Esto es posible??

Comment: ¿Y por que no pruebas asignándolo antes del ciclo en un `option` de HTML regular?

Comment: Si lo pense, pero no sabia se era una buena practica hacerlo de ese modo

Comment: Lo otro sería traer ese valor de la base de datos en una variable e imprimirlo pero para algo que parece estará estático, al menos a mi me parece que con colocarlo de forma directa alcanza

Comment: Pues tienes razón, si me dices que está bien así lo hare de este modo, gracias @BetaM

Comment: No te adelantes, por eso no lo coloqué como respuesta, lo considero al momento una mera opinión, igual esperate a ver que te dicen otros

Comment: Ok, perfecto! espero por si alguien dice algo más

Comment: Concuerdo con @BetaM si sera estatico como un `seleccione...`, entonces no habria problema asignarlo antes del ciclo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hasta donde sé, *Blade* te permite usar ternarios para enviar un valor cuando se cumple la condición y otro cuando no:

```
<select class="form-control formContact" name="pais" id="pais" required>
   <option value="">Selecciona un país</option>
      @foreach ($paises as $pais)
        <option value="{{ $pais->codigo }}" {{ ($pais->codigo == "ES" ? "selected" : "") }}> {{ $pais->pais }}</option> 
      @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Pues funciona perfecto! Es genial @Triby :)

Comment: Excelente, @JuanRivera, gracias por la aclaración.

Comment: no me queda claro.... en realidad es `Blade` y sus `directivas` o es `php` ??? tienen algun link de como se hace eso de `{{ }}` con php???

Comment: En realidad es una declaracion Blade las `{{ }}` que resume `<?php echo ?>`, una directiva es `@if, @elseif, @else, etc` asi que entre los 2, pertenecen a Blade y se usa para agregar `PHP`, mas informacion en la documentacion [blade-directivas](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#blade-directives)

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez, es Blade que interpreta lo que hay dentro de `{{ }}` Referencia: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-data

Comment: @Triby sabes de alguna forma de hacerlo en php sin requerir todo engine template de blade?

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez, PHP, en su origen, era un sistema de plantillas y aún se conserva esa funcionalidad, por tanto basta con `<?php echo $variable; ?>` pero si quieres código limpio y separar lógica de presentación, definitivamente necesitas una librería para manejar plantillas.

Comment: por eso te pregunte si existe alguna manera de remplazar: `<?php echo $variable; ?>` por esto `{{ }}` sin necesidad de pasar por blade como libreria; existe algo mas liviano?

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez, lamentablemente la mayoría de sistemas de plantillas incluyen muchas opciones y algunas son exclusivas de un framework.