# Seleccionar opción por default en select

Tags: php, html, jquery, laravel

actualmente tengo el siguiente select

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="cli">Cliente</label>
        <select name="cli" class="form-control selectpicker" id="cli" 
          data-live search="true">  
          <option value="">Seleccione el cliente</option>
           @foreach($clientes as $cliente)
           <option value="{{$cliente->cuit}}_{{$cliente->nombre}}">{{$cliente->cliente}}</option>
         @endforeach
    </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

El select despliega el listado de cliente y luego separo el array para obtener los campos nombre y cuit, mi consulta es como hago para que tome una cliente por defecto?

Comment: Es decir ¿que antes del listado principal aparezca uno por defecto?, de ser así entonces ¿qué criterio debes seguir para determinar ese registro?

Comment: el registro es uno que tengo en la base de datos ejemplo cuit: 11111, hay 500 y tomaria ese particularmente

Comment: Guíate de lo que respondió @Triby, nadamäs que en el if ternario en lugar de evaluar el lenguaje evaluarías que el id sea igual a 11111 y si es así entonces le das el atributo selected, pero ya con ese ejemplo queda resuelta tu duda

Comment: Gracias lo voy a revisar y les comento si me sirve, saludos

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda me fue de 10 miles de gracias

Answer (score 1):

Esta pregunta ya fue respondida aquí: [Por defecto opción marcada en un select dinamico](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/415050/por-defecto-opci%c3%b3n-marcada-en-un-select-dinamico)

Sin embargo, la adaptaré a tu especificación, aunque veo que ya fue resuelto pero podrías servirle de ayuda a un tercero.

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="cli">Cliente</label>
        <select name="cli" class="form-control selectpicker" id="cli" 
          data-live search="true">  
          <option value="">Seleccione el cliente</option>
           @foreach($clientes as $cliente)
               <option
                   value="{{ $cliente->cuit }}_{{ $cliente->nombre }}"
                   {{ $cliente->cuit == 11111 ? 'selected' : ''}}
               >
                   {{$cliente->cliente}}
               </option>
         @endforeach
    </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

En el ejemplo anterior, si varios coinciden con el criterio, se seleccionará el último, por eso la idea sería que sea un campo que no se vaya a repetir. La operación consistió en una operación ternaria, que es como un if que se realiza en una sola linea.

En este caso, cuando $cliente->cuit sea igual a 11111, se adicionará el atributo "selected" al option, más si no es así, se añadirá una string vacía ''.