# Iterar input radio y marcar una opción automáticamente

Tags: php, laravel

estoy iterando categorías de un blog en forma de input radio. La pregunta es puedo dejar una de ellas marcada? Me gustaría que se quedara seleccionada la de sin categoría que es la `id 1``

```
@foreach ($categorias as $item)
   <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input subcategoriaSaca" type="radio" name="categoria" id="categoria{{ $item->id }}" value="{{ $item->id }}" required checked>
      <label class="form-check-label" for="categoria{{ $item->id }}" style="color: #333;position: relative; top: -4px;">{{ $item->valor }}</label>
    </div> 
@endforeach
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Por defecto opción marcada en un select dinamico](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/415050/por-defecto-opci%c3%b3n-marcada-en-un-select-dinamico)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como dices que la de categoria igual a 1 debe estar marcada lo puedes hacer de esta forma:

```
@foreach ($categorias as $item)
    @php 
       $checked = ($item->id == 1)? 'checked':'' 
     @endphp
   <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input subcategoriaSaca" type="radio" name="categoria" id="categoria{{ $item->id }}" value="{{ $item->id }}" required {{$checked}}>
      <label class="form-check-label" for="categoria{{ $item->id }}" style="color: #333;position: relative; top: -4px;" >{{ $item->valor }}</label>
    </div> 
@endforeach
```

Comment: Hola @Gerardo Marroquin justo te iba a decir eso tiene que ser `@php $checked = ($item->id == 1)? 'checked':'' @endphp` por lo demás funciona estupendo. Muchas gracias

Comment: No entiendo para que meter a `@php`, lo mas simple sería solo un simple condicional evaluando la clave `id` de cada objeto iterado, si el valor es igual a 1 entonces se procede

Comment: @BetaM todos programamos de formas diferentes y siempre habrán miles de formas de llegar al mismo resultado, si tu tienes una idea diferente de hacer puedes publicarlo, todos estamos abiertos a conocer nuevas formas de programar :)